# C pointer arithmetic confusion

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have to answer if the following code compiles and which are the results:

```
char *s1 = "A String";
char *s2 = "Other String";
*s1 = *s2;
```

I didnt really find what happens in the background when you do declarations like that. Is s1 pointing to memory looking like this?:

```
|A| |S|t|r|i|n|g|\0|
```

In my understanding `*s1 = *s2` is the same like `s1[0] = s2[0]`, right?
So why do I get a memory error?
Shouldnt it be?:

```
|O| |S|t|r|i|n|g|\0|
```

Answer (score 1):

Literals strings in C are really *read only* arrays of characters, and can (and should) not be modified.

Attempting to modify the contents of a string literal leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Always make it a habit to use `const char *` when having pointers to string literals.